# Do we know the Chow groups of spheres?

Tags: chow-groups, algebraic-cycles, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field (of char. not $2$) and $X_k=\text{Spec} (k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2-1))$. Do we know the Chow groups $A_i (X_k)$?   I could not find any references, even for $X_{\mathbb R}$.

What (I think) I know: the K-groups were computed by [Swan](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1971371),  so we know the total Chow group up to torsions. In codimension $1$ (i.e., class groups) I am fairly certain the answers are known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book

[The Algebraic and Geometric Theory of Quadratic Forms.](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~karpenko/publ/Kniga.pdf) by R. Elman, N. Karpenko and A. Merkurjev (American Mathematical Society Colloquium Publications, 56., American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2008. 435 pp.)

contains a lot of information. I was just reading

B. Totaro, The automorphism group of an affine quadric, Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. (2007) vol. 143 (1) pp. 1-8

and he is referring to this book for information on Chow groups of spheres.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, this looks promising. I will try to look at it carefully when I have some time. 